# $4$ digit numbers divisible by $5$ formed with $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> How many $4$ digit number divisible by $5$ can be formed with
>   the digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ and $6$?

$a.)\ 220\\
\color{green}{b.)\ 249}\\
c.)\ 432\\
d.)\ 288 $

I tried

Case $1$.  $\text{ _ _ _ 0}$.

$7\times 6\times 5=210$.

Case $2$.  $\text { _ _ _ 5}$.

$7\times 6\times 6=252$.

total ways=$462$.

But the answer given in books is $b.)\ 249$

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Comment: Are considering the digits are repeated , or not repeated.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: But it is not given in question that digit should be repeated explicitly, In case, the digits are not allowed to be repeated , what will be the approach.

Comment: For non-repeated your approach is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to divide it in two cases. But the whole answer treats the two $6$'s as different digits which they are not. Consider $6065$. This will be counted twice in your solution, once as $6_106_25$ and once as $6_206_15$

One possible solution would be to divide it in 2 cases:

- At most one $6$ is present

  Then you just have to count $4$ digit numbers divisible by $5$ using digits from $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ at most once. The rightmost digit can be chosen $2$ ways ($0$ or $5$), the rest can be chosen in $6, \ 5,\ 4,$ ways, giving a total of $$2 \times 6 \times 5 \times  4  =240$$
- Both $6$'s are present.

  The rightmost digit can be chosen $2$ ways ($0$ or $5$). The two $6$ can placed in three places in $3$ ways. The other digit can be chosen $5$ ways, giving a total of $$2 \times 3 \times 5 =30$$

Now, note that this allows leading $0$'s. Since, there can be at most one leading 0, we need to subtract numbers of the form 0 _ _ 5. Avoiding repeatation, we can fill the rest two in $5 \times 4=20$ ways. And there is $0665$ which we haven't counted. So, there are $21$ numbers of the form 0 _ _ 5.

Hence the answer is: $$240+30-21=249$$

Comment: Be careful.  The two $6$'s can be placed in three places in $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ ways.  You can still make your argument work since there are more than $11$ numbers of the form $0\_\ \_5$.  One case is that they are both $6$'s.  For the remaining cases, select the hundreds digit and the tens digit when they are distinct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, I kind of made a blunder there.